# transition opacity not working when creating element

Tags: javascript, html, css

transition opacity from 0 to 1 is not working. here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/ax4aLhjq/19/

```
//html
<div id="a">
  <div style="height:20px"></div>
</div>

//css
#a{
  width:200px;
  background-color:salmon;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height:200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#a .item{
  margin:0px 5px;
  background-color:teal;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

//js
function add(){

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className ="item";
  var newtext = document.createTextNode("aa");
  div.appendChild(newtext);
  document.querySelector("#a").appendChild(div);


  var separator = document.createElement("div");
  separator.style.height="10px";
  document.querySelector("#a").appendChild(separator);


  //apply opacity
  div.style.opacity=1;


}
setInterval(add,3000);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: opacity goes from 0 to 1, not  to 100.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the post, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the answer here: https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/
It appears that when an element is added, repaint is needed and somehow the browser is trying to optimize the computation, and is doing the opacity=0 and opacity=1 in the same cycle. 
The solution is to use `getComputedStyle` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

> " getComputedStyle() in combination with accessing a property value
>   actually flushes all pending style changes and forces the layout
>   engine to compute our ’s current state"

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(elem);

// Make the element fully transparent.
elem.style.opacity = 0;

// Make sure the initial state is applied.
window.getComputedStyle(elem).opacity;

// Fade it in.
elem.style.opacity = 1;
```

Comment: Sadly https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/ no longer exists :(

Answer (score 4):

**Problem:**

You are setting the `opacity`to `1` the same time you were creating the element.

**Solution:**

You have to delay tha action of showing the element, you need to set the opacity within a timeout to make the animation effect otherwise all elements will be just appended.

You can see this snippet I used a `setTimout`to make the effect of the opacity animation:

```js
//js
function add(){

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className ="item";
  var newtext = document.createTextNode("aa");
  div.appendChild(newtext);
  document.querySelector("#a").appendChild(div);


  var separator = document.createElement("div");
  separator.style.height="10px";
  document.querySelector("#a").appendChild(separator);


  //apply opacity
  setTimeout(function(){
      div.style.opacity=1;
  }, 2000);


}
setInterval(add,1000);
```

```css
//css
#a{
  width:200px;
  background-color:salmon;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height:200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#a .item{
  margin:0px 5px;
  background-color:teal;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div style="height:20px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a feeling that was the problem. is it because when you add an element , you add it with opacity=1 and no transition is required?

Comment: Yes, in fact you were adding the element and giving it `opacity=1` at the same time.

Comment: strange. because I add the element to the DOM then change opacity.

Comment: @DouaBeri, there's no `then` here because the two actions are made in the same time interval.

Comment: Yeah. I realized that after I did more digging.

Answer (score 0):

Make a setTimeout like this *window.setTimeout(function(){div.style.opacity=1;},17);*. So the animation will effect next time.

Comment: Thanks. that solution was already provided, but it seems is not 100% bullet proof. Check this: https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/